# Using a loop to append query variables to a message

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of emails that I'm using to find paired their respective `CourseID` in a MySQL.

The loop should be finding each `CourseID` associated with that `email` and append it onto a message and then send it out when it's done. However, the email sends out the first `$row['CourseID']` it finds and doesn't show the rest of the message or any other `$row['CourseID']` that was found.

Here is my code, can anyone tell me what am I missing?

```
 <?php
  $courseList=array();
  $studentList=array();
  $subject="Course Surveys";
  $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

  //populate the course list array
  foreach ($_POST['queue'] as $cID)
    { 
    array_push($courseList, $cID);
    }
  //find all the student emails in each course and put them into an array
  for ($i=0; $i<=count($courseList);$i++)
    {
      $theCourse=$courseList[$i];
      $foundemails=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT StudentEmail FROM Students WHERE CourseID='$theCourse'");
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($foundemails)){
      array_push($studentList, $row['StudentEmail']);

      }
    }
  //strip email array of duplicates & restructure array
  $studentList = array_unique($studentList);
  $studentList = array_values($studentList);

  //Send emails
   for ($i=0;$i<=count($studentList);$i++)
   {

    $message = "Hello ".$studentList[$i].", please take the time to complete the following surveys:\n";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Students WHERE StudentEmail='$studentList[$i]'"); /* USE ORDER BY StudentEmail */
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $hashed=md5($studentList[$i].$row['CourseID']);    
    $message .= $row['CourseID'].":\n http://khaledkloub.com/projects/admin/survey.php?id=".$hashed."\n";
    }
    mail($studentList[$i], $subject, $message, "From: Course Survey Manager\n");
   }

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Why did you use while if you just want to get the courseid of the student?

Comment: Could you post the previous SQL query that you're using to obtain the result of `$studentList`? I believe you might be able to resume it all into a single query.

Comment: As I understand it, it goes through the CourseIDs it finds for that student. There's more than 1. Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$message .= $row['CourseID']."\n";
```

OR

```
$message = $message . $row['CourseID']."\n";
```

Comment: You're fast Prix! I couldn't even get back to edit in the code delineation as fast as you!!

Comment: I'll post the entire script in a second.

Comment: Just a thought along Prix's thinking: turn  the `queue`s into a comma separated string $queue, then for "find all Student emails" do SELECT UNIQUE StudentEmails that are IN $queue.  For "send emails" foreach would be nicer.

Comment: @MarkKasson you mean `DISTINCT` but that will not yield all the entries if not used along with `GROUP BY` which then removes the need of `DISTINCT` since `GROUP BY` have a similar effect.